# Does Deployment Manager templates support Python 3?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

This is about GCP Deployment Manager Templates. Based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/create-a-template) documentation, a Python based deployment manager template must use Python 2.7.

Want to know:

1. Does this mean no support for Python 3?
2. Is a Python version upgrade planned?
3. Is there an ETA for Python 3 support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Yeah, Python 3 is not supported on templates
2 In some courses, some google people say that it is planning but there is not a currently BETA version, I think.

Comment: Looks like now they support Python 3.x - https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/migrate-to-python3